# How to store String and score as (Int or float) in Function

Tags: c++

## CODE

```
void DrawString(float x, float y, const string& score, float * color)

void DrawString(60, 250, "SCORE =" &score, scolor)
```

## CONFUSION

What I am getting is that 1st argument takes x-coordinate, second takes y-coordinate and I am messing up with third one where I have to take a string and integer side by side.

## HOW TO TAKE SUCH VALUES?

Comment: What ist this `"SCORE =" &score`?

Comment: Third one just takes a normal string. `const` means that it won't be modified, `&` prevents a copy assignment. Remove the `&score` part

Comment: I want to print String as "Score = " and an integer whose value is constantly changing ...

Comment: @talal, you need to show more code and define your question better. If you just need to print that, you can hardcode that string in the DrawString function. The second function you showed is also a definition since you noted `void` first, you aren't actually calling it.

Comment: Someone Just Answered it below, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options.

The first is to take the string variable itself:

```
DrawString(60, 250, score, scolor);
```

The second is to pass a string literal to the function:

```
DrawString(60, 250, "SCORE =", scolor);
```

If you want to concatenate these two strings, you can use option 1 like this:

```
std::string tmp = "SCORE = " + score;
DrawString(60, 250, tmp, scolor);
```

---

Also, there is no need to use the `void` keyword when you call the function. In fact, I believe it's counter productive. I have updated my answer accordingly.